# getlist on flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

using the request.form.getlist in Flask, I only get the last value of a list. 
Here below the .py code and html related.
If I suppress the following three lines, then I get the full list, but so doing I miss the headers of the html table rows.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_entries')}}" method=get>
<td width="50"><font size="2">{{ L }}</font></td>   
</form>
```

What should I do ? Thanks for any hint !

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

data = [
('t', 0, 'a'),
('t', 0, 'b'),
('t', 0, 'c'),
('t', 0, 'd')
 ]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_entries():
  entries=[]
  for (i,v) in enumerate(data):
     entries.append(data[i][2])
  return render_template('layout2.html', entries=entries)

@app.route('/get', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_entries():
  cl1=[]
  cl1=request.form.getlist('cn')
  return render_template('test2.html', cl1=cl1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.debug = True
   app.run()
```

The layout2.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<table>

{% for L in entries %}
<tr>
<form action="{{ url_for('show_entries')}}" method=get>
<td width="50"><font size="2">{{ L }}</font></td>   
</form> 
<form action="{{ url_for('get_entries')}}" method=post>
<td width=100 align=center><input type=text name=cn size=3 value=0.0></td>
</tr>
{% if loop.last==True %}
    </table>
    <br>
    <div ALIGN=left>
    <input type=submit value=Submit>
    </form>
    </div>
{% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

The test2.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<div ALIGN="center">
<td width="50"><font size="2" face="verdana" color="red">OUTPUT=</font></td>
<form action="{{ url_for('get_entries')}}" method=get></form>
<td width="50"><font size="2" face="verdana" color="red">{{ cl1 }}</font></td>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening multiple `form` elements but only closing one of them - this is probably causing the browser to only send over the *last* form - and hence only one value is being sent over.  Wrap your `form` around the entire table instead (and remove the nested form) and `getlist` will work.

Answer (score 3):

The only direct descendants that a `<tr>` element can have are `<td>` and `<th>` elements. You can't have a `<form>` element in there.

Put your `<form>` tag inside of the `<td>` and it should work:

```
<td width="50">
    <form action="{{ url_for('show_entries')}}" method=get>
        <font size="2">{{ L }}</font>
    </form>
</td>
```

Also, your HTML is outdated:

- The `<font>` tag is deprecated.
- Similarly, the `align` attribute is also deprecated.

Style things with CSS.

Comment: In other words, deprecated code (what a shame...) is not having any effect on the the [getlist](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/?highlight=getlist#werkzeug.datastructures.Headers.getlist) .... please focus on the title of this topic...